# Best Metric to Determine Statistical Significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I'm doing a study on vaccine hesitancy and need to compare the results of my study to the population. My study asks 3000 medical professionals if they would be willing to take the Covid vaccine, and they respond yes, no, or undecided.

I would like to compare the numbers of my study to the American population as a whole. For instance, if only 1000 out of the 3000 in my study elected to receive the vaccine, but 50% of Americans are willing to receive it, I want to know if my study suggests that medical professionals are less likely to elect to receive the vaccine by a statistically significant margin.

**Edit:**
I did the Chi-Sq test in Excel but am worried because my p-value is 0.0000. I then did it manually and got the same answer. I posted a screenshot below. Am I doing this incorrectly?

[image: Chi-Sq test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the populations are independent with respect to willingness to receive vaccine, (and samples are random) a two-proportion z-test would be an appropriate test for significant difference in proportions

where $x_i$ is number who said they would get vaccine in group i 
and $n_i$ is total responses in group i

$H_0$: proportion of group 1 ($p_1 = \frac{x_1}{n_1}$) = proportion of group 2 ($p_2= \frac{x_2}{n_2}$) 
$H_A$: Difference in proportions

z = $\frac{p_1 - p_2}{\sqrt{(\frac{x_1+x_2}{n_1+n_2})(1-\frac{x_1+x_2}{n_1+n_2})(\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2})}}$

Use z-score table or online calculator to find p-value of your z-statistic

For Dependent Populations:
I suggest trying the Chi-Sq test for Independence to determine if there is an association between group (Medical professional and American population) and Vaccine hesitancy

For a chi-sq of large magnitude, a tiny p-value is expected. Check out this online calculator if you want to double check your calculations

[Chi-Sq Calculator](https://socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/default2.aspx)

Comment: One population is a subset of the other. Population A is the entire American adult population. Population B is a sample of 3000 CNAs. Is the two-proportion z-test still the way to go?

Comment: @ClaytonC check out the Chi-Sq test for independence. It will determine if association between group and vaccine hesitancy is present

Comment: If $n_1 \approx n_2,$ you'd need to know how many of those in the larger group are also members of the smaller. // But I suppose there are large polls in the entire population. Say that $n_2 = 10000,$ and $x_2 = 7000,$ so that $\hat p_2 = 0.7 \approx p_2.$ Then you can get an idea whether $\hat p_1 = 850/1024 = 0.83$ is significantly greater than 0.7 by using `binom.test` in R, where `binom.test(850, 1024, .7, alt="g")$p,val` returns $\approx 0,$ firmly rejecting $H_0$ // The main remaining question is whether Yes to vaccination in the larger gp means the same thing as Yes to vacc in smaller.

Comment: I'll take a look at Chi-Sq. Thanks.

Comment: @jros I edited the question to show my work for the chi-sq test. Am I doing this right? My p-value equated to 0.

Comment: @ClaytonC. for a chi-sq of that magnitude, a tiny p-value is expected. Check out this online calculator if you want to double check your calculations https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/default2.aspx

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you put that as an answer and I'll close the question? Much obliged.

Comment: @ClaytonC. I've edited my original answer to include, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yessir, all good. Thanks!